# Как вернуть индекс в многоуровневом списке?

Tags: python, массивы, list, index

Как найти индексы следующих цифр: 7, 48, 83?

Есть ли легкое решение по типу L.index(48)

```
L = [[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]], 
    [[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30], [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]], 
    [[41, 42, 43, 44, 45], [46, [47, 48], 49, 50], [51, 52, 53, 54, 55], [56, 57, 58, 59, 60]], 
    [61, 62, 63, [64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71], 72, 73, 74, [75, [76, 77, 78], 79], 80], 
    [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]]
```

Comment: Указывайте в тегах предпочитаемый язык, иначе непонятно, в каком виде вы хотите получить ответ.

Comment: И что вы хотите получить после выполнения `L.index(48)`? У вас несколько массивов, в массиве и потом эти массивы в одном массиве. Относительно первого элемента индекс получить?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Я хочу узнать индекс числа 48. Как найти именно индекс и вытянуть по индексу данное число. Простите, если я не совсем ясно довожу свою мысль.

Comment: @RashidkhanAkhmedov Ну хорошо какой индекс будет у числа 48? `[2][1][1]`???

Answer (score 5):

Готового решения вроде нет. Можно найти вот так через рекурсию:

```
def find_index(obj, num, ind = None):
    if ind == None:
        ind = []
    for i,el in enumerate(obj):
        ind.append(i)
        if isinstance(el, int):
            if el == num:
                print(f'{num}: {"".join([f"[{x}]" for x in ind])}')
        else:
            find_index(el, num, ind)
        ind.pop()

for i in [7, 48, 83]:
    find_index(L, i)
```

Вывод:

```
7: [0][0][6]
48: [2][1][1][1]
83: [4][2]
```

Проверим:

```
print(L[0][0][6], L[2][1][1][1], L[4][2])
```

Вывод:

```
7 48 83
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что я никогда в жизни не пойму.........
В любом случае, спасибо вам большое!

Comment: @RashidkhanAkhmedov Да в общем-то это просто рекурсивный обход списка, в списке `ind` при этом находится текущая цепочка индексов, тут довольно не сложно, если по шагам разобрать. Вот печать текущего индекса это да - несколько навороченная получилась, но тоже можно разобраться при желании )

Comment: @RashidkhanAkhmedov И отметьте ответ галочкой, если он вам помог

Answer (score 1):

Почти продублирую логику в соседнем ответе, но приведу реализацию, использующую механизм исключений и встроенный метод поиска элемента в списке. Да, и пусть функция возвращает значение индекса.

```
def find_index(obj, num, ind=None):
    if ind is None:
        ind = []
    for i, el in enumerate(obj):
        ind.append(i)
        try:
            ind.append(el.index(num))
            break
        except ValueError:
            ind, is_ok = find_index(el, num, ind)
            if is_ok:
                break
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        ind.pop()
    else:
        return ind, False
    return ind, True


for n in 7, 48, 83, 101:
    print(*find_index(L, n))

# [0, 0, 6], True
# [2, 1, 1, 1], True
# [4, 2], True
# [], False
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, за более детальный разбор.
Буду откровенен, больше половины указанных способов мне не ясны, надеюсь в скором времени я всё безусловно пойму и даже больше, я смогу достойно обсудить с вами эту тему.